# SQL Server : get min(lastupdatedate) from each status of that id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find durationdays. I want to get min(lastupdatedate) of that status for each studentid and minus from next min(lastupdatedate) of that status. If there is no next status available then we have to consider getdate(). If I have only 1 status for a given studentid then min(lastupdatedate)-getdate()

```
 CREATE TABLE mytable
 (
     id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
     studentid int NOT NULL,
     status VARCHAR(7),
     createddate DATE,
     lastupdatedate DATE,
     durationdays INT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO mytable(studentid, status, createddate, lastupdatedate) 
 VALUES
    (1,'New','2/15/2019','2/15/2019')
   ,(1,'Open','2/15/2019','2/25/2019')
   ,(1,'Sub','2/15/2019','3/17/2019')
   ,(1,'PS','2/15/2019','3/27/2019')
   ,(1,'PI','2/15/2019','5/11/2019')
   ,(1,'PR','2/15/2019','5/15/2019')
   ,(1,'PI','2/15/2019','5/27/2019')
   ,(1,'PC','2/15/2019','8/25/2019')
   ,(1,'PI','2/15/2019','9/4/2019')
   ,(1,'PI','2/15/2019','10/24/2019')
   ,(1,'PC','2/15/2019','11/5/2019')
   ,(1,'RC','2/15/2019','11/16/2019') ;
```

Output

```
  studentid   status    createddate lastupdatedate  duration_days
--------------------------------------------------------------------
     1         New      2019-02-15  2019-02-15          10
     1         Open     2019-02-15  2019-02-25          20
     1         Sub      2019-02-15  2019-03-17          10
     1         PS       2019-02-15  2019-03-27          45
     1         PI       2019-02-15  2019-05-11           4
     1         PR       2019-02-15  2019-05-15          12
     1         PI       2019-02-15  2019-05-27          90
     1         PC       2019-02-15  2019-08-25          10
     1         PI       2019-02-15  2019-09-04          50
     1         PC       2019-02-15  2019-11-05          11
     1         RC       2019-02-15  2019-11-16          34
```

Comment: That `INSERT` doesn't work; your `VALUES` clause has 4 columns, but the `INTO` declares 5.

Comment: It makes little sense to name a column studentid which is bit and then use the phrase "for a given studentid"  and THEN to provide data where every row has the same value for that column. Did you intend to refer to ID in your description and ouput - since that seems to match the idea that a row represents a student (in some fashion).

Comment: The student ID field should be an INT, not a BIT, correct?

Comment: It seems that you are basing the usage of GETDATE() as if were 10 days before 2/15/2019 as if you align the values that would be the only way you get the outcome in your results.

Comment: Not sure I got you...I may be wrong in duration_days count...But I think you got glimpse what am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

This query does what you asked above, however, subtracting GETDATE() when there are no lag dates to pull from results in a very odd datetime.

```
DECLARE @GetDate DATETIME ='02/05/2019'

SELECT 

    id,studentid,status,createddate,
    lastupdatedate,
    NextLastModifiedDateByStudentStatus = LEAD(lastupdatedate) OVER(PARTITION BY studentid,status ORDER BY lastupdatedate),
    derivednextupdatedate= ISNULL(LEAD(lastupdatedate) OVER(PARTITION BY studentid,status ORDER BY lastupdatedate),@GetDate),
    daysapart =  ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,ISNULL(LEAD(lastupdatedate) OVER(PARTITION BY studentid,status ORDER BY lastupdatedate),@GetDate),lastupdatedate))
FROM 
    @mytable
ORDER BY 
    studentId, status, lastupdatedate
```

Comment: I think there is a difference between how you stated the question and expected results. Can you re-word it to make it more clear.

Comment: Above query is giving wrong count. Basically, I want...min(lastupdatedate) of that status for a given studentid and minus of next min(lastupdatedate) available status for same student id. If next min(lastupdatedate)  is not available then we have to use getdate()

Comment: This means you want the lastmodified for each student/status pair ordered by lastmodified? I don't know what you mean by the next min(lastmodified) for each student/status. That would be the next lastmodified in an ordered list, correct? In your original question you asked to take the min(lastmodified) of each student/ status.

Comment: yes. I want lastupdatedate order by for that status minus lastupdatedate  of next status. If there is no next status then we have to consider getdate function.

Comment: Then, I would re-phrase the question as "give me the days between the lastupdateddate for each student/status ordered by lastupdateddate. If the next lastupdatedate does not exists by group key then use getdate() as the subtrant. Or something like that. The min() threw me of a bit.

Comment: Modified to int

Comment: Since the question contradicts the output I answered it based on what "I think" you are asking. For each student/status record subtract the lastmodifed date from either the next lastmodified date, in sequential order,  of the same grouping, or getdate(), if the value does not exist. However, my values are very much off from  what you posted. Good luck on your quest for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The description of your logic doesn't line up with the sample data you have in your desired output. To achieve the sample data, you just need to apply the `LEAD` function to your existing data.

```
SELECT
  *,
  DATEDIFF
    (
      DAY,
      lastupdatedate, 
      LEAD(lastupdatedate,1,GETDATE()) OVER (PARTITION BY studentid ORDER BY lastupdatedate)
    ) as durationdays
FROM 
  @mytable
```

Results:

```
+----+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
| id | studentid | status | createddate | lastupdatedate | durationdays |
+----+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
|  1 |         1 | New    | 2019-02-15  | 2019-02-15     |           10 |
|  2 |         1 | Open   | 2019-02-15  | 2019-02-25     |           20 |
|  3 |         1 | Sub    | 2019-02-15  | 2019-03-17     |           10 |
|  4 |         1 | PS     | 2019-02-15  | 2019-03-27     |           45 |
|  5 |         1 | PI     | 2019-02-15  | 2019-05-11     |            4 |
|  6 |         1 | PR     | 2019-02-15  | 2019-05-15     |           12 |
|  7 |         1 | PI     | 2019-02-15  | 2019-05-27     |           90 |
|  8 |         1 | PC     | 2019-02-15  | 2019-08-25     |           10 |
|  9 |         1 | PI     | 2019-02-15  | 2019-09-04     |           50 |
| 10 |         1 | PI     | 2019-02-15  | 2019-10-24     |           12 |
| 11 |         1 | PC     | 2019-02-15  | 2019-11-05     |           11 |
| 12 |         1 | RC     | 2019-02-15  | 2019-11-16     |           37 |
+----+-----------+--------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
```

This shows the time for *any* change in status, although your description talks about changes within each status.

Comment: I already tried this..it will not work if I have only 2 records like this... INSERT INTO mytable(studentid,status,createddate,lastupdatedate) VALUES
 (1,'PI','2/15/2019','9/4/2019')
 ,(1,'PI','2/15/2019','9/24/2019')